# Error using CTE in SQLITE3

Tags: sql, sqlite, common-table-expression

I use these codes to get level(depth) of my parent/child categories table. and the isLeaf attribute:

```
with cteCat as (
select 
    id, parent,
    [cteLevel]  = 1
from Categories 
where 1=1 and parent=0
union all 
select 
    c.id, c.parent,
    [cteLevel] = cc.cteLevel+1
from Categories c
join cteCat cc
    on c.parent = cc.id
where 1=1
    and c.parent <> 0
)
select 
* 
, CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Categories c2 WHERE c2.parent = c1.id) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsLeaf
, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Categories c2 WHERE c2.parent = c1.id) AS Leafs
 from cteCat c1
 order by c1.id
```

result is:

```
 id     parent  cteLevel    IsLeaf  Leafs
 1      0       1           0       2
 ....
```

it's OK in SQLSERVER. but when i execute at sqlite, I get Error:

```
Error while executing SQL query on database 'ado': 
no such column: cc.cteLevel
```

Any help? thanks.

Comment: `[cteLevel]  = 1` is invalid SQL. Not sure if SQLite supports those non-standard `[` but as far as I know it does not support assignment of variables like that - unless this is a non-standard column alias, then you need to write `1 as ctelevel` (and of course `cc.ctelevel + 1 as cteLevel` in the second part)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite does not support variable assignments like this.

However, you should be able to do the same with standard SQL:

```
WITH cteCat AS (
  SELECT id,
         parent,
         1 AS cteLevel
  FROM ...
  WHERE ...
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c.id,
         c.parent,
         cc.cteLevel + 1
  FROM ...
  WHERE ...
)
SELECT ...
```